# How to count particular DN value's number in image in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to count the the number of particular DN value. I have tried to use mask and loop to do it, but it's so slow if the image is big. Here is my code (the variable 'image' is a image):

```
    var y =[]
for (var yr= 1856; yr <= 1890; yr = yr + 1) {
 var mask =imgae.eq(yr)
 var sumDictionary = mask.reduceRegion({
   reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
   region:aoi.bounds(),
   scale: 30,
   maxPixels: 1e9
 });

  y[yr-1856]=sumDictionary
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not easily reproducible since I don't have access to the resources, but theoretically this should work. The 'trick' is to use a server-side function `iterate` to do the looping (read https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/client_server)

```js
var years = ee.List.sequence(1856, 1890)

var y = ee.Dictionary(years.iterate(function(yr, dict) {
  dict = ee.Dictionary(dict)
  yr = ee.Number(yr)
  var mask =image.eq(yr)
  var sumDictionary = mask.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    region: aoi.bounds(),
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e9
  });
  return dict.set(yr, sumDictionary)
}, ee.Dictionary({})))

print(y)
```